# Problem with GWT hosted mode when doing Ctrl+F5 in Chrome : CSS don't render anymore

Tags: css, firefox, gwt, google-chrome, gwt-hosted-mode

I have a weird problem on my GWT app in hosted mode. I did a "CTRL+F5" on my web page and since then, my app css didn't render anymore. Now, I have an ugly app with nothing more than labels and no styling elements even though I have verified that all resources (css, images and so on) are present.

Even weird fact, the app renders normally on Internet Explorer (never thought I would put IE and normally in the same sentence :D) but it's not working on Chrome and Firefox.

Has anybody already experienced this in dev mode ? It's getting me crazy ... please help ...

thanks in advance

Comment: What does Control+F5 do?

Comment: Control+F5 is supposed to refresh the page and clear cache in the same time

Comment: Did you try the obvious?
Shut down dev server.
Clear all history,cookies etc in FF.
Restart server, reload page

Comment: I have already tried it : it's even easier since I am in hosted mode. So I just shut down the server, cleared cookies too ... even cleared cache but it's still not working in Chrome and FF ... but it's ok on IE

Answer (score 0):

"Ugly" page means that your css does not load anymore. IE possibly caches them so page still renders properly.

Use developer console on Chrome or firebug on Firefox to inspect loading of resources.

Chrome: right-click on any element -> Inspect Element -> select Network tab -> reload page

Comment: I tried it, I can see on the resource list that my CSS gets loaded correctly...weird!